# New elements added with AJAX are not working with .on

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(".add_rows").on( "click", function() {
    alert('in here');
    $.post( "add_row.php", function( data ) {
        $( "#add_row_here" ).append( data );
    });
});
```

In my PHP output I have the following:

```
<a class="btn small fr add_rows" id="formsubmitswitcher">Add Rows</a>
```

I thought the .on command would still allow me to click this link and trigger this code again. Why is this not working as I would expect it to?

Comment: Read http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events starting with the 4th paragraph.

Comment: .on isn't a magic wand, you have to use it correctly for it to do what you want it to do. You specifically used it in such a way that would make it NOT delegate the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try event delegation using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#add_row_here").on( "click",".add_rows" function() {
    alert('in here');
    $.post( "add_row.php", function( data ) {
        $( "#add_row_here" ).append( data );
    });
});
```

**Syntax**

```
$(closest-parent-element).on(event,"selector" function() {});
```

instead document you can use closest parent element

Comment: Don't use `document` though. He's clearly using `#add_row_here` as the container for these elements, so that should be where the `on` is bound.